# C# String tokenization

Tags: c#, .net, regex, tokenize, subtraction

I write a math C# application where user can define functions in a predefined way, such as

```
COS({x}+3*(2+SQRT({x})))
```

For the evaluation I use the Shunting-Yard algorithm. I have a function to tokenize the string above which produces the following input in a list:

> FUNCTION,OPEN_PARENTHESIS,VARIABLE,OPERATOR,NUMBER,OPERATOR,OPEN_PARENTHESIS,NUMBER,OPERATOR,FUNCTION,OPEN_PARENTHESIS,VARIABLE,CLOSE_PARENTHESIS,CLOSE_PARENTHESIS,CLOSE_PARENTHESIS.

This works well but I have problems with negative numbers, I don't know how to handle the subtraction operator, when subtraction and when negative sign?

The function iterates through the string and searches patterns in it (for example when the i. character is '{' then (i+1). character have to be a small letter and (i+2). character have to be '}', stores the variable and go on with the (i+3). character, otherwise it throws a syntax error.) Now this function accepts negative numbers and instead of subtraction it accepts multiplication with negative number and use '+', so instead of 3-1 I have to use 3+(-1)*1. This is not an elegant solution, have you got any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

if you see a - at the start of the line, immediately after an open parenthesis or following another symbol then the number that follows is negative

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small open source library that can parse C# style expressions.

https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso

You can write custom functions (like COS, SQRT), inject variables or parameters (x). Or you can use built-in C# functions (Math.Sqrt, ...).

You can find a live demo at: http://dynamic-expresso.azurewebsites.net/

Maybe this library can speed up your work.